# How should I go about recreating the iOS home screen open folder animation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation

At first I thought it wouldn't be too hard, but turns out there's a bit more to it than I thought.

[image: iOS Folder Open]

At the moment my code's based around this: https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders. However, it's not very clean, the biggest problem being that it takes a screenshot every time the folder opens (renderInContext: is pretty taxing on the CPU so turns out being very low fps). Aside from that this implementation doesn't look as clean and as polished as the Apple animation does.

Apple manages to pull off a pixel perfect animation that doesn't lag. I'd like to do the same! What is the best way to go about this/how would you do this - a cleanly coded, good looking and fluid animation? At the moment, my animation's lacking in all those areas, and I'm stumped about how I could do it better (like Apple does it).

-

I'm not begging for code, just a best method/how to. But if you want to go ahead and code it then there's no way I'd say no (that would definitely be bouty worthy)!!

Comment: Do you just want to know how Apple does it (assuming that they do it in an App Store-compliant way)?  Your comments on vikingsegundo's answer make it sound like you have a requirement Apple doesn't have.  Apple's folder-opening only has to split the wallpaper, but your comments make it sound like you want to have more views that cross the seam and split in two.

Comment: @robmayoff my situation is slightly different from the way Apple does it - just pretend the folders are not aligned nicely and that it what I have. However I'm interested in knowing how Apple does it, if it's done in a way that doesn't work in my situation then fine by me. Splitting up the wallpaper isn't how Apple does it according to sudo rm -rf . The answer below isn't incorrect - I'm just waiting to see if anyone has a better answer.

Comment: @robmayoff also splitting the wallpaper isn't as straightforward as it's made to seem below. Firstly, rotation (on an iPad) means the wallpaper is positioned differently behind icons when rotated. Also, depending what folder is clicked, each view is going to have to be assigned to a different 'backing view' to be added to depending whether it's gonna split up or down (based on what folder was tapped). Folders rotate when open too. Combine all these problems and it actually results in something that's pretty messy - I'm not convinced that this is how Apple does it, there may be a better way.

Comment: It's not too hard to understand how Apple does it.  First, set a wallpaper in the simulator (and restart the simulator to make it take effect).  Then attach the debugger to SpringBoard and use `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` before and after opening a folder to see how Apple reconfigures the view hierarchy.  I've done this and it doesn't seem to me that they're doing anything you can't do.

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the Springboard into several views, where each view is one row of icons.
If a folder icon is clicked, I would animate all following views to move down and up to make place for the folder content. at the same time I would add a subview that represents the folder content and animates with the same speed its size and position if necessary.

To support a background image that spans over the whole screen I would cut that into pieces and add this pieces as background image views to each row's view.

---

I wrote a quick and dirty sample code with the animation starting on any tap location, also available as [complete project on github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/VSFolderAnimation).

[image: screenshot]

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *upperView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *lowerView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *upperImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *lowerImageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *folderContentsView;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect startRect;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *bgImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    self.upperImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImg];
    self.lowerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImg];
    [self.upperImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
    [self.lowerImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];

    self.upperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.upperImageView.frame];
    self.lowerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.lowerImageView.frame];
    [self.upperView addSubview:_upperImageView];
    [self.lowerView addSubview:_lowerImageView];

    [self.view addSubview:_lowerView];
    [self.view addSubview:_upperView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *upperTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                         action:@selector(openOverlay:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *lowerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                         action:@selector(openOverlay:)];

    [self.upperView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.upperView addGestureRecognizer:upperTapRecognizer];
    [self.upperView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [self.lowerView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.lowerView addGestureRecognizer:lowerTapRecognizer];
    [self.lowerView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    self.folderContentsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.folderContentsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *closeTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                         action:@selector(closeOverlay:)];
    [self.folderContentsView addGestureRecognizer:closeTapRecognizer];
    [self.view addSubview:self.folderContentsView];

    [self.folderContentsView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgFolder.png"]]];
    [self.folderContentsView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    self.startRect = [self.upperView frame];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)openOverlay:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.upperView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.lowerView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:sender.view];

    self.folderContentsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, location.y,
                                    _lowerView.frame.size.width, 0);
    self.lowerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, location.y,
                                      _lowerView.frame.size.width, _lowerView.frame.size.height);
    self.upperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                      _upperView.frame.size.width, location.y);
    self.lowerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(_lowerImageView.frame.origin.x, -location.y,
                                           _lowerImageView.frame.size.width, _lowerImageView.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.folderContentsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, location.y,
                                    _lowerView.frame.size.width, 200);
        self.lowerView.frame = CGRectOffset(_lowerView.frame, 0, 200);
    }];    
}

-(void) closeOverlay:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.lowerView.frame = CGRectOffset(_lowerView.frame, 0, -200);
        self.folderContentsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.folderContentsView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.folderContentsView.frame.size.width, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.upperView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.lowerView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        self.upperView.frame = self.startRect;
    }];
}


@end
```

two views a equipped with the same background in layers. If a tap is detected, both views are resized so that the upper view ends at the tap's y-coordinate, while the lower view starts there. the UIImageView added to the lowerView is moved in the opposite direction, so that the images stays in place.

Now the lowerView slides down while a contentView is added and resized at the same speed.

As you can see no image rendering or other tough action is required. just UIView animations.

[image]

Comment: This is probably not too far from how it's done. You can also imagine it as a table view with expandable rows.

Comment: @jrturton, I actually thought of proposing the usage of a table view with expandable cells. but that would depend of more knowledge of the real use case.

Comment: Is there a way I could split a UIView into pieces dynamically? This is a great solution, the only problem being that my folder will drop down from an arbitrary position, meaning that I can't separate the background view beforehand unfortunately

Comment: if you take the ios springboard, it has 5 rows on iPhone 5. each row should be represented by a view. so the background images should be cut in to 5 pieces and each view gets its own background images. you can do that all upfront once.

Comment: or you dont cut at all but add the same background image to each view with changing the uiimageview's frame to by in sync with the previous views backgrounds.

Comment: @vikingosegundo for me though, the animation starts from an arbitrary point that's only specified when the user taps where the folder will open from (it's not a recreation of the iOS springboard exactly). Great idea, just in my case it's not going to work.

Comment: Actually I happen to know exactly how it was done, and no it's not through chopping up the views into separate panes. Apple "cheats" in their implementation. ;) Also, I'm the creator of JWFolders, and I do realize it needs to be cleaned up. The reason why I chose to take a screenshot is for maximum flexibility for any view hierarchy. It is not the most performant, but you can't make one size fits all for this sort of thing.

Comment: @sudorm-rf, I never claimed to know how it was done. An I never had a look at your code. I just answered the question how it *could* be done.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Hey I wasn't accusing you of anything! Just thought I'd pop in here and keep the OP updated.

Comment: @sudorm-rf, so everything if fine.

Comment: @sudorm-rf hey, the solution I'm going for is based on your JW-Folders :) I've optimised it a bit (actually, I've made some pretty mega changes ha...) the main idea being that the stationary part of the container view doesn't need to have a screenshot taken if the content view is masked correctly. Using CGContextConcatCTM you can shift the location of the container view's context before calling renderInContext, meaning that the size of the screenshot taken is a lot smaller (and takes up a lot less memory... a 10mb screenshot isn't cool!). Also I've added things like animating the notch alpha.

Comment: @sudorm-rf If you'd like, I can send you the code if you'd like to see what I've done. It's a bit messy, and I've removed a whole lot of functionality that I didn't need - meaning that it's not really worth adding on git hub. But if you'd like to see what I've done to optimise the original JWFolders then you're welcome to!

Comment: @sudorm-rf also, I'm extremely interested in how Apple does it?? Even if they do use a private API.

Comment: @vikingosegundo hey, thanks. Unfortunately for me, chopping up the views isn't a great solution. Not all view hierarchies and layouts lend well to doing that, especially if you've gotta chop labels when the folder opens then this solution won't work :) But this solution could be helpful for other users!! Thanks

Comment: @Jordan I am not chopping anything, the labels could be placed on the backgroundviews — twice.

Comment: @vikingosegundo that's pretty messy when you've got a whole lot of labels (and other views actually) that are all over the background view. In my case, it's really not a clean solution - in fact, it gets very messy very quickly. It would also take a lot of time/CPU to create every view I'm using twice. Unfortunately duplicating UIViews isn't possible, I've already looked into that. I'm not saying that your solution is incorrect, in some cases this would be more than fine - just that it really depends on the situation. In my case, it would create more problems than it would solutions.

Comment: @Jordan, what is wrong with labels on the background view? lables need to be on a view, if that voew again is in a nother view doesnt matter. also how any hundreds views do you plan to push in there? if you are concerned about the view overhead you can try layers. adn about copying labels: you could either have a clean factory or you implement  the NSCopy protocol in a category.

Comment: @Jordan Yeah sure, you can find my email on my [GH profile](https://github.com/jwilling).